# Cambiar la ruta absoluta a la ruta relativa en AODB con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, rutas

Estoy intentando acceder a la base de datos cars.mdb ubicada dentro del proyecto.

Cuando accedo por la ruta absoluta no me da problema, pero quiero acceder por la ruta relativa. Pero cuando lo intento, agrega el directorio C: / a la ruta y no encuentra el archivo. ¿Hay alguna forma de cambiarlo?

Dejo el código aquí:

```
       //var myConnect = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\imcascallana\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\ConexionAccess\\ConexionAccess\\bd\\coches.mdb");
        var myConnect = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\bd\\coches.mdb");
        var ConnectObj = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
        var RS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        var sql="SELECT * FROM coches;";
        ConnectObj.Open (myConnect);
        RS.Close();
        ConnectObj.Close();
```

Gracias de antemano, saludos

Comment: Si esta ubicada dentro de la misma carpeta puedes usar `./`. `cd ./baseDeDatos` La computa reemprasará el punto por la ruta actual. Y si esta en la anterior: `../` `cd ../baseDeDatos` La computadora reemprasará los dos puntos con la ruta de la carpeta padre a la carpeta en donde te encuentras. Al intentar agregar `C:/` lo que hace es buscar en la base de los directorio.

Comment: También lo he intentado, al final la ruta que le introduzco queda de esta forma: `var myConnect = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= cd.. \\bd\\coches.mdb");` Pero, la ruta que me muestra es la siguiente **C:\Users\imcascallana\Desktop\cd.. \bd\coches.mdb**, es decir, me lo añade como un literal mas.

Comment: no pongas `cd` deja solo los puntos. CD es un comando MS-DOS. Aunque no se si tienes un directorio llamado `cd`. Por ejemplo:  `var myConnect = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= ..\\bd\\coches.mdb")`.Nota: `cd` no forma parte del directorio y puse todo junto: `..\\nameDir`.¿Para evitar confución elimino mi comentario de arriba?.

Comment: Aun probándolo, me sube un nivel en la ruta total, es decir, con la siguiente ruta `var myConnect = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= ..\\bd\\coches.mdb` me daría el resultado de : **C:\Users\imcascallana\bd\coches.mdb**, y nunca llega a buscar directamente dentro del proyecto.

Comment: Porque usaste los dos puntos que es el directorio padre de la carpeta actual. ejemplo: `C:/name1/name2` si estas en la carpeta name2 y usas los dos puntos quedaria así. Nota es un ejemplo de cmd, Dos y bash: `cd ../` directorio actual: `C:/name1`, pero si usas solo uno: `cd ./` quedarias en este directorio: `C:/name1/name2` en otra palabra colocalo así: `Source=./bd/coches.mdb`

Comment: Acabo de probar a ponerlo tal cual : `Source ="./bd/coches.mdb"` pero me vuelve a buscar en toda la ruta y no dentro del propio proyecto : **C:\Users\imcascallana\Desktop\bd\coches.mdb**

Comment: Si pongo la ruta `Source="\\\\bd\\coches.mdb"` me da como resultado **\\bd\coches.mdb**, pero me sigue sin encontrar la base de datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121220/discussion-between-daniel-briceno-and-yuenecrosano).